# How can I prevent letter download after a certain number character Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, text, character

I don't want to download all the characters in the data. Example: First, the first 500 characters should be downloaded automatically, if the user presses "more", all other characters will be downloaded as well.

```
databaseReference =
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post").child(PostKey);

 databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          
            content = dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue().toString();
            txtcontent.setText(content);

   
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Xlm:

```
  <TextView

                android:id="@+id/txtcontent"             
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I want like this : [image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with what you have now.  All database queries will retrieve the **entire** contents of any node that you request, including all nested child nodes.  There are no partial downloads.

The only way to make this work the way you describe is to put only the first 500 characters into the node that you query, and put the rest of the text somewhere else that you can fetch later in a second query.